# Jointjs Rendering issue in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg, jointjs, rappid

Initially the diagram has been rendered, but when click/dragged on the diagram, the boxes(rectangles and ports ) is being hidden in firefox.
But it works as expected in Chrome.

[image]

[image]

Could you please tell me what could possibly be wrong.

Tech stack used is:
Angularjs
Bootstrap

Comment: Without a [mcve] we really can't tell you, no.

Comment: Thank you Robert for ur reply. But i figured the problem myself. The issue was that i was trying to render the diagram when the view was hidden in Angularjs due to which the jointjs was not able to find the dimensions of the diagram. I hope this might help someone else with similar issue

Answer (score 1):

In my case that bug was happen when **scale** my paper (for **zoom** functionality).

I quickly fix it doing a little **translate** of 1px with a **timeout** after doing the **scale**

```js
paper.scale(scaleValue);
...
setTimeout(function(){
  paper.translate(paper.translate().tx + 1, paper.translate().ty + 1);
}, 1);
```